# Trash bin is not opening

Tags: 10.04, trash

My Trash bin is not opening. It just shows the "loading" mouse cursor forever.
Any idea what can be wrong?

**--update (after the answer)**
After emptying the trash solved also a problem that used to occur when I remove the pendrive, saying that "computer:/// could not be localized" or something like this..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three possibilities come to mind, I'll start with the easier first:

1. There is a huge number of files in the trash which is blowing some limitation in nautilus or memory.
2. There is a file in the trash that is causing its respective thumbnail generator to hang
3. There is a hard error on your disk which is being used by something in the trash

There are multiple approaches to clearing the problem:

- install package `trash-cli` which gives you command line programs such as `list-trash` and `empty-trash`, these are most likely "safest" in terms of keeping your trash can in proper form.
- the trash-can is just a couple of directories under `$HOME/.local/share/Trash` which can be inspected and manipulated with `ls` and `rm` from the command line
- look at `/var/log/kern.log` and `/var/log/syslog` for complaints about hard errors on your harddrive.

Comment: "There is a huge number of files in the trash" was a good point. Trying to empty it openned thousands of windows (why? I don't know), and after killing all it is back to normal (looks like).

Answer (score 5):

Honestly, no idea.

You might have more success by loading it through a terminal. Most applications are quite vocal about their crashes and failures but `nautilus` is comparatively silent. Perhaps running it like this `killall nautilus && nautilus trash:///` might show you the problem.

You can forcibly delete everything in trash with this (but remember it will delete everything in there):

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*
```

If you want to rescue something from the trash, I suggest you browse it and pluck out what you need. You can do this from the terminal and you should also be able to do it via nautilus.

If you find the precise problem, or it persists, make sure you file a bug (`ubuntu-bug nautilus`)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it solved deleting the nautilus hidden directory at user's home. Before deleting, you can rename it to see if the problem solve

```
cd
mv .nautilus/ .nautilusx
```

Answer (score 0):

I had more than 20.000 items (files or folders) in the trash, leading to the same problem

First I copied a file I wanted to restore from `~/.local/share/Trash/files/` using [Dolphin](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Dolphin/) or [Thunar](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Thunar/) (nautilus and nemo failed) into the place where I want it to be restored.

I installed

```
sudo apt install trash-cli
```

then you can plot all files into trashList.txt using:

```
trash-list >> trashList.txt
```

(Terminaloutput would be unusable, since trash contains too many files, therefore redirecting to trashList.txt)

If you want to delete files older than 366 days you can use

trash-empty 366

Alternatively you can install autotrash

```
pip install --user autotrash
```

and delete files older than 365 days:

```
autotrash -d 365
```

This answer uses

- https://askubuntu.com/a/327947/676490 (location of trash)
- https://www.2daygeek.com/trash-cli-command-line-trashcan-linux-system/ (how to install and use trash-cli)
- https://github.com/bneijt/autotrash#installation (installation and usage of autotrash)