# How to open "Trash" through terminal?

Tags: command-line, trash

I tried opening Trash by running the command `nautilus`, but it gives me an error.

Comment: Could you be more specific, which error did you get and which command did you use

Comment: Related: [Command to move a file to Trash via Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/q/213533/301745)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

The trash folder should be located under:

```
/home/your_username/.local/share/Trash
```

So you should be able to access it via:

```
cd ~/.local/share/Trash
```

The folder might not exist unless you delete something from the filesystem. In this case you would run into an error (saying that the folder does not exist).

Answer (score 28):

If you want to open Trash using Nautilus run the following:

```
nautilus trash://
```

Comment: Or if you want to open the default app: "gvfs-open trash://". If Nautilus is your default, it will open the trash.

Answer (score 13):

For Ubuntu 18.04 and newer, use [`gio`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/gio.1.html). For older versions, use [`gvfs-ls`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/gvfs-ls.1.html) and [`gvfs-trash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/gvfs-trash.1.html).

To read the trash:

```
gio list trash://
gvfs-ls trash://
```

To send files or directories to the trash:

```
gio trash [FILE or DIR]
gvfs-trash [FILE or DIR]
```

To empty it:

```
gio trash --empty
gvfs-trash --empty
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer now, `gio` works for all mount point, which isn't the case of the accepted answer, also `gio` offers a better cli interface to _trash_ handling

Comment: How to restore/recover a file with `gio`? With trash-clie I can do `trash-restore` and then select a file to restore! I couldn't find an alternative with `gio` .  see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/945550/restore-files-moved-to-trash-using-command-line)

Answer (score 4):

You can list all the files in the trash by using `trash-list`. First, install it by running:

```
sudo apt install trash-cli
```

Now, you can list the files by running:

```
trash-list
```

You may be interested in these other commands too:

| Command | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `trash-restore` | Restore file from trash. |
| `trash` | Command line trash utility. |
| `trash-empty` | Empty trash. |
| `trash-list` | List trashed files. |
| `trash-put` | Put file in trash |
| `trash-rm` | Removes files matching a pattern from the trash can. |