# Unable to open Trash folder in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: trash

I'm having trouble opening my Trash folder in Ubuntu and unable to open and view my deleted files as per normal.

It shows up as:

```
This location could not be displayed.
Sorry, could not display all the contents of “trash:///”: Operation not supported
```

Does anyone knows how to resolve this? I know i can empty the contents in `/.local/share/Trash`, but the Trash directory is also missing as well. I tried to create a new Trash directory but the problem described above still persists.

Greatly appreciate any comments from the community!

Comment: If it helps, you could try accessing the trash via CLI. See my answer here: [How to open “Trash” through terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/a/917820/301745)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create four separate directories (although I'm not sure this approach will actually work for you):

```
mkdir ~/.local/share/Trash
mkdir ~/.local/share/Trash/expunged
mkdir ~/.local/share/Trash/files
mkdir ~/.local/share/Trash/info
```

Let me know your progress on this and I'll update the answer as needed.

Comment: hi!, doesn't seems to resolve the issue though; but when i tried to delete a file, it'll go into /.local/share/Trash/files. But when i access it through the Trash folder, i encounter the same problem with the error message described in the main thread.

Comment: The Trash system might have a mini-database that needs to be rebuilt some how. Or if it's a permission issue try `chmod 700 ~/.local/share/Trash` but I'm not sure if that will solve much.

Comment: yeah i tried working around permission  but still can't solve it, do you've any idea how to rebuild the Trash folder without re-installing ubuntu as i got this workstation from someone else.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating it in /.local, that may be part of the problem. You should be creating ~/.local/share/Trash

That folder should contain subdirectories called expunged, files, and info

Those folders should have permissions of 0700

I cannot replicate your error message, but removing and recreating those files seems to leave a working trash in 17.04

Comment: i checked the permissions, all 3 folders that i added manually can 'create and delete files'