# How can I recover my files and my system after running rm -r /home/username?

Tags: command-line, data-recovery, home-directory

I am new to Linux & was running some random commands to experiment in terminal (Ubuntu-18.04 LTS) & by mistake I deleted my home directory.

The command I executed is shown in the screenshot of my history below. It was

```
rm -r /home/dawn
```

Now all my files are gone, as well as the default folders such as Pictures, Desktop, Screenshots, etc & my desktop screen has turned dark black.

When I tried to open the files icon, it's giving me an error.

Can anyone help me on this?

[image: command history]

[image: unable to find the requested file]

Comment: Have you check your trash folder so you should be able to access it fromthe terminal using the commands in the following link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/327943/how-to-open-trash-through-terminal

Comment: try [this one !!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6698/can-files-directories-deleted-with-rm-be-restored)

Comment: follow the steps outlined here https://askubuntu.com/a/150673/18025   essentially  reboot your machine using the same install medium you used to install ubuntu ( memory stick or DVD) then issue outlined commands

Comment: @Graham if OP deleted $HOME how will they be able to access `~/.local/share/Trash` from the linked post? Also OP, I am curious why you would `rm -r $HOME`? I would suggest using a vm if you are going to experiment with dangerous commands like what you did. That being said there is this https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

Comment: Understood........

Comment: worseeee. I did `sudo rm -rf /home`, and I stopped it midway, but it was too late for that. Now I don't have any wallpaper and most of the apps are broken. And the text on terminal is weird af. But few days ago, I had done a fresh installation on another partition. Thank god for that precious data

Answer (score 0):

- **If you lost some important data try to recover with 'testdisc'.**
- **If no important data is lost and you can boot.** Go to settings>Details>Users unlock and add another user with Administrative powers, set password and login again or reboot. Login as new user from there you can delete the previous user.

I wonder why you did it.

Comment: how will that recover the files?

Comment: It was an experiment

Answer (score 0):

If your **account was new** (without any important/personal files) just re-create your home:

1. Log out current user from GUI.
2. Switch to text console by pressing eg. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
3. Copy fresh user base files and change its ownership:

   ```
   sudo cp -r /etc/skel $HOME
   sudo chown `id -u`.`id -g` $HOME
   ```

   Or:

   ```
   sudo mkhomedir_helper $USER
   ```
4. Log user again to GUI, your additional dirs will be recreated (`Desktop`, `Pictures` etc. - according to `/etc/xdg/user-dirs*`).

Comment: @Zanna there is no $HOME/, it was deleted...

Comment: You are right haha so just that command should do it I think